# Put Error Class if input is empty in step wise form

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap-3, jquery-validate

Hi I am trying to put validations in my form.

**Updated Code**

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.registration-form fieldset:first-child').fadeIn('slow');

    $('.registration-form input[type="text"]').on('focus', function () {
        $(this).removeClass('input-error');
    });

    // next step
    $('.registration-form .btn-next').on('click', function () {
        var parent_fieldset = $(this).parents('fieldset');
        var next_step = true;

        parent_fieldset.find('input[type="text"],input[type="email"]').each(function () {
            if ($(this).val() == "") {
                $(this).addClass('input-error');
                next_step = false;
            } else {
                $(this).removeClass('input-error');
            }
        });

        if (next_step) {
            parent_fieldset.fadeOut(400, function () {
                $(this).next().fadeIn();
            });
        }

    });

    // previous step
    $('.registration-form .btn-previous').on('click', function () {
        $(this).parents('fieldset').fadeOut(400, function () {
            $(this).prev().fadeIn();
        });
    });

    // submit
    $('.registration-form').on('submit', function (e) {

        $(this).find('input[type="text"],input[type="email"]').each(function () {
            if ($(this).val() == "") {
                e.preventDefault();
                $(this).addClass('input-error');
            } else {
                $(this).removeClass('input-error');
            }
        });

    });


});
</script>
```

```css
.input-error {
  color:yellow;
  background-color:red;
}

/*style.css**/






/***** Top content *****/

.form-box {
    padding-top: 0px;
    font-family: Century, Tahoma, Arial, Verdana, Georgia;
              
}

.form-top {
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0 25px 15px 25px;
    background: #008ade;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
    border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
    text-align: left;
    color: #fff;
    transition: opacity .3s ease-in-out;
}

.form-top h3 {
    color: #fff;
}

.form-bottom {
    padding: 25px 25px 30px 25px;
    background: #c3dde8;
    -moz-border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px;
    border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px;
    text-align: left;
    transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
}

.form-bottom:hover {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16), 0 2px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
    box-shadow: 0 2px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16), 0 2px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
}

form .form-bottom button.btn {
    min-width: 105px;
}



form.registration-form fieldset {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section>
   <h1 class="pagetitle"><span>&nbsp;<i class="material-icons md-36">card_travel</i> Create Distributor</span></h1>
</section>


  <div class="assessment-container container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 form-box">
       
            <?php 

            $attributes = array('class' => 'registration-form');
            echo form_open('' ,$attributes); ?>
         
                    <fieldset class="registration-form">
                        <div class="form-top">
                        <div class="form-top-left">
                            <h3><span><i class="material-icons md-36">account_balance</i>&nbsp;</span>Organization Information</h3>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-bottom">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="form-group col-md-6 label-floating">
                                <label for="i5" class="control-label">Organization Name</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="" class= "form-control" required title="This Field is Required">
                                </div>
                            <div class="form-group col-md-6 label-floating">
                                <label for="i5" class="control-label">Pincode</label>
                                <input type="text" name="" required class= "form-control">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group label-floating"">
                            <label for="i5" class="control-label">Address 1</label>
                            <input type="text" name="" class= "form-control">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group" style="margin-bottom:3px;">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="form-group col-md-5 label-floating">
                                    <label for="i5" class="control-label">City</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="" class= "form-control">
                                    <span class="help-block">City Organization</span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group col-md-5 label-floating">
                                    <label for="i5" class="control-label">State</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="" class= "form-control">
                                    <span class="help-block">Insert a State</span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group label-floating"">
                            <label for="i5" class="control-label">Country</label>
                            <input type="text" name="" class= "form-control">
                            <span class="help-block">Insert a State</span>
                        </div>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-next" style="margin-top: 20px;">Next</button>
                    </div>
                    </fieldset>


                    <!--END OF ORGANIZATION INFORMATION -->
                       <fieldset>
                        <div class="form-top">
                            <div class="form-top-left">
                                <h3><span><i class="material-icons md-36">account_box</i></span>Sales & Technical Contact</h3>
                                
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-bottom">
                                
                        <h4>Sales Contact</h4>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="form-group col-md-6 label-floating">
                                <label for="i5" class="control-label">First Name</label>
                                      <input type="text" name="" class= "form-control">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group col-md-6 label-floating">
                                    <label for="i5" class="control-label">Last Name</label>
                                     <input type="text" name="" class= "form-control">
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="form-group col-md-6 label-floating">
                                <label for="i5" class="control-label">Email</label>
                                     <input type="text" name="" class= "form-control">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group col-md-6 label-floating">
                                    <label for="i5" class="control-label">Phone</label>
                                     <input type="text" name="" class= "form-control">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            


                            <h4>Technical Contact</h4>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="form-group col-md-6 label-floating">
                                <label for="i5" class="control-label">First Name</label>
                                     <input type="text" name="" class= "form-control">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group col-md-6 label-floating">
                                    <label for="i5" class="control-label">Last Name</label>
                                      <input type="text" name="" class= "form-control">
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="form-group col-md-6 label-floating">
                                <label for="i5" class="control-label">Email </label>
                                     <input type="text" name="" class= "form-control">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group col-md-6 label-floating">
                                    <label for="i5" class="control-label">Phone</label>
                                     <input type="text" name="" class= "form-control">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            
                             <button type="button" class="btn btn-previous" style="margin-top: 20px;">Previous</button>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-next" style="margin-top: 20px;">Next</button>
                        </div>
                    </fieldset>



                    <fieldset>
                        <div class="form-top">
                            <div class="form-top-left">
                                <h3><span><i class="material-icons md-36">https</i></span>Distributor Information</h3>
                                
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        
                        <div class="form-bottom">
                            

                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="form-group col-md-6 label-floating">
                                <label for="i5" class="control-label">Distributor Username</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="" class= "form-control">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group col-md-6 label-floating">
                                    <label for="i5" class="control-label">Distributor Password</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="" class= "form-control">
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <h4>Number of License for products</h4>
                            
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="form-group col-md-6 label-floating">
                                <label for="i5" class="control-label">MLC</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="" class= "form-control">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group col-md-6 label-floating">
                                    <label for="i5" class="control-label">FMS</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="" class= "form-control">
                                </div>
                            </div>



                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="form-group col-md-6 label-floating">
                                <label for="i5" class="control-label">UMC</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="" class= "form-control">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group col-md-6 label-floating">
                                    <label for="i5" class="control-label">PTT</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="" class= "form-control">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            
                            

                       

                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-previous">Previous</button>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-raised btn-info">Submit</button>
                        </div>
                    </fieldset>


<?php echo form_close();?>
               
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Now this is Multi Level Form. I want to add error class if a value is kept empty on the required field For eg organization name is required field.

Now I want to show error class when next button is pressed. What is wrong with my code ?

[image: form class]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `class="registration-form"` to your form or to some element containing your next button as I did by adding to `<fieldset class="registration-form">`

I also added css to make inputs have red background when there is an error, check output below:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.registration-form fieldset:first-child').fadeIn('slow');

    $('.registration-form input[type="text"]').on('focus', function () {
        $(this).removeClass('input-error');
    });

    // next step
    $('.registration-form .btn-next').on('click', function () {
        var parent_fieldset = $(this).parents('fieldset');
        var next_step = true;

        parent_fieldset.find('input[type="text"],input[type="email"]').each(function () {
            if ($(this).val() == "") {
                $(this).addClass('input-error');
                next_step = false;
            } else {
                $(this).removeClass('input-error');
            }
        });

        if (next_step) {
            parent_fieldset.fadeOut(400, function () {
                $(this).next().fadeIn();
            });
        }

    });

    // previous step
    $('.registration-form .btn-previous').on('click', function () {
        $(this).parents('fieldset').fadeOut(400, function () {
            $(this).prev().fadeIn();
        });
    });

    // submit
    $('.registration-form').on('submit', function (e) {

        $(this).find('input[type="text"],input[type="email"]').each(function () {
            if ($(this).val() == "") {
                e.preventDefault();
                $(this).addClass('input-error');
            } else {
                $(this).removeClass('input-error');
            }
        });

    });


});
```

```css
.input-error {
  color:yellow;
  background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<fieldset class="registration-form">
<div class="form-top">
    <div class="form-top-left">
        <h3><span><i class="material-icons md-36">account_balance</i>&nbsp;</span>Organization Information</h3>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-bottom">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-6 label-floating">
            <label for="i5" class="control-label">Organization Name</label>
                <input type="text" name="" class= "form-control" required title="This Field is Required">
            </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-6 label-floating">
            <label for="i5" class="control-label">Pincode</label>
            <input type="text" name="" required class= "form-control">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group label-floating"">
        <label for="i5" class="control-label">Address 1</label>
        <input type="text" name="" class= "form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group" style="margin-bottom:3px;">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group col-md-5 label-floating">
                <label for="i5" class="control-label">City</label>
                <input type="text" name="" class= "form-control">
                <span class="help-block">City Organization</span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-5 label-floating">
                <label for="i5" class="control-label">State</label>
                <input type="text" name="" class= "form-control">
                <span class="help-block">Insert a State</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group label-floating"">
        <label for="i5" class="control-label">Country</label>
        <input type="text" name="" class= "form-control">
        <span class="help-block">Insert a State</span>
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-next" style="margin-top: 20px;">Next</button>
</div>
</fieldset>
```

Question progressed:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('fieldset:first-child').fadeIn('slow');

    $('input[type="text"]').on('focus', function () {
        $(this).removeClass('input-error');
    });

    // next step
    $('.btn-next').on('click', function () {
        var parent_fieldset = $(this).parents('fieldset');
        var next_step = true;

        parent_fieldset.find('input[type="text"],input[type="email"]').each(function () {
            if ($(this).val() == "") {
                $(this).addClass('input-error');
                next_step = false;
            } else {
                $(this).removeClass('input-error');
            }
        });

        if (next_step) {
            parent_fieldset.fadeOut(400, function () {
                $(this).next().fadeIn();
            });
        }

    });

    // previous step
    $('.btn-previous').on('click', function () {
        $(this).parents('fieldset').fadeOut(400, function () {
            $(this).prev().fadeIn();
        });
    });

    // submit
    $('button[type="submit"]').on('click', function (e) {
        
        $(this).parents('fieldset').find('input[type="text"],input[type="email"]').each(function () {
            if ($(this).val() == "") {
                e.preventDefault();
                $(this).addClass('input-error');
            } else {
                $(this).removeClass('input-error');
            }
        });

    });


});
```

```css
.input-error {
  color:yellow;
  background-color:red;
}

/*style.css**/






/***** Top content *****/

.form-box {
    padding-top: 0px;
    font-family: Century, Tahoma, Arial, Verdana, Georgia;
              
}

.form-top {
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0 25px 15px 25px;
    background: #008ade;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
    border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
    text-align: left;
    color: #fff;
    transition: opacity .3s ease-in-out;
}

.form-top h3 {
    color: #fff;
}

.form-bottom {
    padding: 25px 25px 30px 25px;
    background: #c3dde8;
    -moz-border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px;
    border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px;
    text-align: left;
    transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
}

.form-bottom:hover {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16), 0 2px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
    box-shadow: 0 2px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16), 0 2px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
}

form .form-bottom button.btn {
    min-width: 105px;
}



form.registration-form fieldset {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section>
   <h1 class="pagetitle"><span>&nbsp;<i class="material-icons md-36">card_travel</i> Create Distributor</span></h1>
</section>


  <div class="assessment-container container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 form-box">
       
            <?php 

            $attributes = array('class' => 'registration-form');
            echo form_open('' ,$attributes); ?>
         
                    <fieldset class="registration-form">
                        <div class="form-top">
                        <div class="form-top-left">
                            <h3><span><i class="material-icons md-36">account_balance</i>&nbsp;</span>Organization Information</h3>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-bottom">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="form-group col-md-6 label-floating">
                                <label for="i5" class="control-label">Organization Name</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="" class= "form-control" required title="This Field is Required">
                                </div>
                            <div class="form-group col-md-6 label-floating">
                                <label for="i5" class="control-label">Pincode</label>
                                <input type="text" name="" required class= "form-control">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group label-floating"">
                            <label for="i5" class="control-label">Address 1</label>
                            <input type="text" name="" class= "form-control">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group" style="margin-bottom:3px;">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="form-group col-md-5 label-floating">
                                    <label for="i5" class="control-label">City</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="" class= "form-control">
                                    <span class="help-block">City Organization</span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group col-md-5 label-floating">
                                    <label for="i5" class="control-label">State</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="" class= "form-control">
                                    <span class="help-block">Insert a State</span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group label-floating"">
                            <label for="i5" class="control-label">Country</label>
                            <input type="text" name="" class= "form-control">
                            <span class="help-block">Insert a State</span>
                        </div>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-next" style="margin-top: 20px;">Next</button>
                    </div>
                    </fieldset>


                    <!--END OF ORGANIZATION INFORMATION -->
                       <fieldset>
                        <div class="form-top">
                            <div class="form-top-left">
                                <h3><span><i class="material-icons md-36">account_box</i></span>Sales & Technical Contact</h3>
                                
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-bottom">
                                
                        <h4>Sales Contact</h4>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="form-group col-md-6 label-floating">
                                <label for="i5" class="control-label">First Name</label>
                                      <input type="text" name="" class= "form-control">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group col-md-6 label-floating">
                                    <label for="i5" class="control-label">Last Name</label>
                                     <input type="text" name="" class= "form-control">
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="form-group col-md-6 label-floating">
                                <label for="i5" class="control-label">Email</label>
                                     <input type="text" name="" class= "form-control">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group col-md-6 label-floating">
                                    <label for="i5" class="control-label">Phone</label>
                                     <input type="text" name="" class= "form-control">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            


                            <h4>Technical Contact</h4>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="form-group col-md-6 label-floating">
                                <label for="i5" class="control-label">First Name</label>
                                     <input type="text" name="" class= "form-control">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group col-md-6 label-floating">
                                    <label for="i5" class="control-label">Last Name</label>
                                      <input type="text" name="" class= "form-control">
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="form-group col-md-6 label-floating">
                                <label for="i5" class="control-label">Email </label>
                                     <input type="text" name="" class= "form-control">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group col-md-6 label-floating">
                                    <label for="i5" class="control-label">Phone</label>
                                     <input type="text" name="" class= "form-control">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            
                             <button type="button" class="btn btn-previous" style="margin-top: 20px;">Previous</button>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-next" style="margin-top: 20px;">Next</button>
                        </div>
                    </fieldset>



                    <fieldset>
                        <div class="form-top">
                            <div class="form-top-left">
                                <h3><span><i class="material-icons md-36">https</i></span>Distributor Information</h3>
                                
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        
                        <div class="form-bottom">
                            

                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="form-group col-md-6 label-floating">
                                <label for="i5" class="control-label">Distributor Username</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="" class= "form-control">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group col-md-6 label-floating">
                                    <label for="i5" class="control-label">Distributor Password</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="" class= "form-control">
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <h4>Number of License for products</h4>
                            
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="form-group col-md-6 label-floating">
                                <label for="i5" class="control-label">MLC</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="" class= "form-control">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group col-md-6 label-floating">
                                    <label for="i5" class="control-label">FMS</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="" class= "form-control">
                                </div>
                            </div>



                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="form-group col-md-6 label-floating">
                                <label for="i5" class="control-label">UMC</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="" class= "form-control">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group col-md-6 label-floating">
                                    <label for="i5" class="control-label">PTT</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="" class= "form-control">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            
                            

                       

                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-previous">Previous</button>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-raised btn-info">Submit</button>
                        </div>
                    </fieldset>


<?php echo form_close();?>
               
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: is that the only change you did or is it something else as well? because i have added the class using codeigniter forms like this <?php 

            $attributes = array('class' => 'registration-form');
            echo form_open('' ,$attributes); ?>

Comment: i am adding the screenshot please check

Comment: Did you add css to make background red?

Comment: No, actually I am trying to add my default bootstrap error class

Comment: i tried adding the css error class you gave  as well but still there is some issue

Comment: Add it temporarily just to see if you get some change as I do with the "Run code snippet" above...

Comment: I am adding my full code please check if it works for you

Comment: It works for your first one... I'll check but you probably don't have the class around the second and on-wards forms...

Comment: OKay let me try

Comment: last example I removed classes from button click as an alternative...thanks for the accept :)

Answer (score 0):

now it works,, you have couple of double quote signs in element class declarations,,, like this: `class="form-group label-floating""` I only cleaned it a bit :)

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.registration-form fieldset:first-child').fadeIn('slow');

    $('.registration-form input[type="text"]').on('focus', function () {
        $(this).removeClass('input-error');
    });

    // next step
    $('.registration-form .btn-next').on('click', function () {
        var parent_fieldset = $(this).parents('fieldset');
        var next_step = true;

        parent_fieldset.find('input[type="text"],input[type="email"]').each(function () {
            if ($(this).val() == "") {
                $(this).addClass('input-error');
                next_step = false;
            } else {
                $(this).removeClass('input-error');
            }
        });

        if (next_step) {
            parent_fieldset.fadeOut(400, function () {
                $(this).next().fadeIn();
            });
        }

    });

    // previous step
    $('.registration-form .btn-previous').on('click', function () {
        $(this).parents('fieldset').fadeOut(400, function () {
            $(this).prev().fadeIn();
        });
    });

    // submit
    $('.registration-form').on('submit', function (e) {

        $(this).find('input[type="text"],input[type="email"]').each(function () {
            if ($(this).val() == "") {
                e.preventDefault();
                $(this).addClass('input-error');
            } else {
                $(this).removeClass('input-error');
            }
        });

    });


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="registration-form"> 
<fieldset>
                        <div class="form-top">
                            <div class="form-top-left">
                                <h3><span><i class="material-icons md-36">account_balance</i>&nbsp;</span>Organization Information</h3>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-bottom">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="form-group col-md-6 label-floating">
                                <label for="i5" class="control-label">Organization Name</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="" class= "form-control" required title="This Field is Required">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group col-md-6 label-floating">
                                    <label for="i5" class="control-label">Pincode</label>
                                     <input type="text" name="" required class= "form-control">
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group label-floating">
                            <label for="i5" class="control-label">Address 1</label>
                              <input type="text" name="" class= "form-control">
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group" style="margin-bottom:3px;">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="form-group col-md-5 label-floating">
                                        <label for="i5" class="control-label">City</label>
                                          <input type="text" name="" class= "form-control">
                                       <span class="help-block">City Organization</span>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group col-md-5 label-floating">
                                        <label for="i5" class="control-label">State</label>
                                          <input type="text" name="" class= "form-control">
                                        <span class="help-block">Insert a State</span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>


                            <div class="form-group label-floating">
                              <label for="i5" class="control-label">Country</label>
                                         <input type="text" name="" class= "form-control">
                                        <span class="help-block">Insert a State</span>
                            </div>

                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-next" style="margin-top: 20px;">Next</button>
                        </div>
                    </fieldset>
  
  </div>
```

Comment: it did not work, when i clicked on next it still does nothing, it does not allow me to go to next step but at the same time i want to show error class on my input div

Comment: while typing the input field i get error class if i miss anything, but i want this to be triggerd also when i click on next button so user can understand that he has done some mistake